# How to change shipping method title based on cart amount?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I applied a 5% discount to the Woocommerce cart, based on cart amount and shipping method, which seems to be working fine. But I cannot manage to change the shipping method title when the rule applies, i need to add a message "5% discount" to all local-pickup methods.

I found a workaround using conditional shipping, but that won´t work in this website, I need to use the same method, but adding a message to the title.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
function local_pickup_discount( $cart ) {
  $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
  $carrito_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
  $chosen_shipping_no_ajax = $chosen_methods[0];
  
  if ( 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping_no_ajax, 'local_pickup' ) && $carrito_total < 60000) {
    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.05; // 5% discount applied here
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Descuento por retiro en sucursal', 'yourtext-domain' ) , -$discount ); // Fee descripton
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'local_pickup_discount');
```

Thanks in advance, I know this must be a very simple thing to do, but I am not used to working with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this hook to rename your label `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label`. Inside you can apply any conditional logic you want and output label with custom one.

**Note: This label is used in both cart and checkout. So if you want it only on checkout add condition is_checkout() or is_cart() if you want to limit it.**

```
function wc_change_local_pickup_label( $label, $method ) {
    $carrito_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    if ( $carrito_total < 60000 && 'local_pickup' === $method->method_id) {
        $label = "Local pickup 5% discount";
    }

    return $label;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'wc_change_local_pickup_label', 10, 2 );
```